# How to reverse GP-LVM Gaussian process latent variable and reconstruct original variables using python?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, dimensionality-reduction

GP-LVM an be used for dimensionality reduction. After such dimensionality reduction is performed, how can one approximately reconstruct the original variables/features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [GPy](https://gpy.readthedocs.io/en/deploy/GPy.models.html), you can use the `predict` function, which returns the predictive mean and variance:

```py
import numpy as np
from   GPy.models import GPLVM

m = GPLVM(Y, input_dim=2)
m.optimize()
mean, var = m.predict(m.X)
print(np.linalg.norm(Y - mean, 2))
```